# AssociationTypeMismatch problem when saving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in a previous question i was stumped.. but stack overflow provided the solution

my two models

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fixtures, :finder_sql => 'SELECT * FROM fixtures where (home_team = #{id} or away_team = #{id})'
  has_many :home_fixtures, :class_name => "Fixtures", :foreign_key => :home_team
  has_many :away_fixtures, :class_name => "Fixtures", :foreign_key => :away_team
  has_many :teamalias
end

class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  belongs_to :selection
  has_many :selection

  named_scope :for_team_id, lambda{|team_id| {:conditions => ['(home_team = ? or away_team = ?)', team_id, team_id]} }
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => :home_team
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => :away_team


  def fix_list
    [home_team.title, "Draw", away_team.title]
  end
end
```

taken from 
[Multi level associations in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362212/multi-level-associations-in-rails)

but I'm stumped again- i'm trying to save a fixture based on the last solution in the first answer above and I am getting a typemismatch of.

Team(#38391330) expected, got String(#1242130)

no idea what to do here please help.

edit- db migrations

Here is the migrations

class CreateFixtures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :fixtures do |t|
      t.integer :home_team
      t.integer :away_team
      t.datetime :when
      t.integer :league_id

```
  t.timestamps
end
```

end

def self.down
    drop_table :fixtures
  end
end

class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :title

```
  t.timestamps
end
```

end

def self.down
    drop_table :teams
  end
end

class AddResultToFixture < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :fixtures, :result, :integer
  end

def self.down
    remove_column :fixtures, :result
  end
end

Comment: Can you share the relevant database schema as well?

Comment: Could you show the code and where this error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form probably has `fixture[home_team]` which is a select which passes the `team.id`

so when you do

```
@fixture = Fixture.new(params[:fixture])
@fixture.save
```

you are calling `home_team= team.id` team.id is a string but home_team should be a Team object