# Pull objects from an association into an array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, associations

A user `has_many :donations`, a project `has_many :donations`, and a donation `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :project`.

I'm looking for a sensible way to extract the projects associated with a user (through donations) into an array.

I'm currently doing:

```
def index
  @user = User.find params[:user_id]
  @projects = []
  @user.donations.each do |donation|
    @projects << donation.project
  end
end
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, as this seems lame. Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**

I accidentally simplified this too far. A user can also be associated with a project through other models, so `@projects = @user.projects` isn't going to do what I need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :donations
  has_many :projects, :through => :donations
  …
end

@user.projects
```

should work.

For gathering many association collections see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362212/multi-level-associations-in-rails/1362348#1362348). You will need to adapt it to use the through associations (just treat them as normal has_masnys), but the same applies.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot some important info - I've added another requirement.

Comment: For the record, the linked answer uses named scopes:  

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html